# Finding if 1 vector is included in 2nd vector

Tags: c++

I need to write a program that finds out if one of the 2 vector is included in another one.
The program works like this.

1 - Gets the `m` and `n` values from `input.txt` (1st row)

2 - Resizes `verctorM` and `vectorN` to `m` and `n`, then fills them with numbers from `input.txt` (2nd row for `vectorM`, 3rd row for `vectorN`)

3 - After filling, the program should find out wich one of the vectors has the fewest "characters" by comparing `n` and `m`

4 - The program gets the first "character" of "small" vector and start to compare it with the "characters" of "big" vector ()

5 - When the statemant `vectorN[i] = vectorM[0]` is correct, the program compares the next "characters" if every "character" of "small" vector is in the "big" vector, program output `1`, if not continues to compare with 1st "caracter" of "smal" vector, if "small" vector is not included in "big" vector, program outputs `0`

Edit - the numbers must be in same order as written in `input.txt`

Here is the code that I ended up with

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

int m;
int n;

bool y = false;

vector<int> vectorM;
vector<int> vectorN;

ifstream file1;
file1.open("input.txt");
file1 >> m;
file1 >> n;

vectorM.resize(m);
vectorN.resize(n);

for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
    file1 >> vectorM[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    file1 >> vectorN[i];
}

//this is the part that I need help with


ofstream file2;
file2.open("output.txt");

if (y == false)
    file2 << 0;
else
    file2 << 1;

}
```

What's the efficent way to compare the "characters" ??

Example, if in `input.txt`

```
 4 3
 1 2 3 2
 1 2 3
```

Program outputs `1`, because 1 2 3 is in 1 2 3 2, but if

```
 2 3
 1 2
 2 3 1
```

Program outputs `0`

Comment: The algorithm described in the assignment is wrong. The vectors can have duplicates. Consider for example two vectors. One is { 1, 2, 3, 4 } and other is { 1, 1, 1 }. The approach that is described yields the result 1 though the smallest vector is not included in the  biggest vector.

Comment: when the statement is correct, the program compares the next character, in your example when `V1` is `{1,2,3,4}` and `V2` is `{1,1,1}` , the program compares the `V1[i]` with `V2[0]`, when statement is correct the program compares `V1[i+1]` with `V2[1]`, when statement is incorrect, the program starts to find another `i`

Comment: Well just make minor changes V1{ 2, 3, 1, 4 } and V1 { 1, 1, 1 }. And how the loops wil work?

Comment: @AramayisAntonyan: You want to test for a contiguous subsequence inside another range?There's a standard library algorithm that does what you want. Do you have to implement this yourself?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow when `i=2`, the statement is correct, so the program compares the next value `V1[3]` and `V2[1]`. 4 is not equal to 1, so the program gets the new `i` wich is `3`, the statment is incorrect, so the program outputs `0`

Comment: @Aramayis Antonyan As I said the algorithm is incorrect because before i = 2 there is an element that can be equal to some other element in V2. But you skip it. Consider V1 { 2, 3, 1, 4 } and V2 { 1, 2, 1 }  Using your approach number 2 will not be found in V1. ,

Comment: @AramayisAntonyan For example this array { 1, 2, 3 } is contained in array { 3, 2, 1 }. However using your approach  the result will be negative.

Comment: Yes and the program will output `0`, I'm very bad at exlaning things, so let me try another exampple, if V1=(1,2,2,2,3) and V2=(2,2,3), the output will be `1`, because there are 2,2,3 elements in the same order, but when V1=(1,2,3,2,3) and V2=(2,2,3) the output will be `0`, because there are no 2,2,3 elements in the same orders

Comment: @AramayisAntonyan: You're looking for the exact second sequence, together and in order, in the first sequence? That's what [std::search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) does. Are you allowed to use the standard library?

Comment: If there is no <algorithm> use it will be better, but can you please give me an example how the std::search will work in this example?

Comment: @AramayisAntonyan: I already posted an answer showing std::search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're asking if a contiguous subsequence can be found inside another range of values. The standard library [`std::search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) algorithm does just that.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool included(const std::vector<int>& seq, const std::vector<int>& sub)
{
    return std::search(seq.begin(), seq.end(), sub.begin(), sub.end()) != seq.end();
}

int main()
{
    auto v1 = std::vector<int>{ 1,2,3,2 };
    auto v2 = std::vector<int>{ 1,2,3 };

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << included(v1, v2) << '\n';

    auto v3 = std::vector<int>{ 1,2 };
    auto v4 = std::vector<int>{ 2,3,1 };

    std::cout << included(v3, v4) << '\n';
}
```

[Demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/WntswW)

Note: I stole Jarod42's function name and coincoin's test data.

Comment: I think this is what OP wants indeed.